# What is the runtime complexity of this code? The code is given in the description

Tags: java, loops, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

Am I right in saying that the runtime complexity of this code is (2N + 2)?

```
public static int[] mystery1(int[] list) {
    int[] result = new int[2*list.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        result[2 * i] + list[i] / 2 + list[i] % 2;
        result[2 * i + 1] = list[i] / 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: not sure why the +2 but I would say the complexity of this code is in O(n)

Comment: To calculate the complexity then you should to look at the number of loops, don't look to another thing, so in your case you have one loop so the complexity is `O(N)`

Comment: Consider runtime of c_0 for the whole assignments inside the loop. They consume 2nc_0. For loop always checks the condition n+1 times, therefore it consumes 2nc_1. There are also another lines of code which are executed one time, I consider them to take c_3. The answer is 2n(c_0+c_1)+c_3 which is O(n)

Comment: We drop constants when reporting the complexity. O(2n + 2) is properly written as O(n).